# openstack image create throws BadRequestException

Tags: openstack, qemu, ceph, openstack-glance

I've installed `ussuri` version of `openstack` and everything seems to be fine, but there is a wierd problem in glance. When I use `glance image-create` command, everything is fine and it works correctly, but, when I use `openstack image create` command, as I mentioned below:

```
openstack image create --public --protected --disk-format raw --file ubuntu.raw ubuntu
```

it throws this execption:

> BadRequestException: 400: Client Error for url: http://controller:9292/v2/images, Provided object does not match schema 'image': 'True' is not of type 'boolean': Failed validating 'type' in schema['properties']['protected']:: {'description': 'If true, image will not be deletable.',: 400 Bad Request: 'True': 'type': 'boolean'}: On instance['protected']:

I'm using `CEPH` for `Glance` backend but Openstack have been stored images in `/var/lib/glance/images`!
this is my `glance-api` config file:

```
[DEFAULT]
[cinder]
[cors]
[database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://glance:password@controller/glance
[file]
[glance.store.http.store]
[glance.store.rbd.store]
[glance.store.s3.store]
[glance.store.swift.store]
[glance.store.vmware_datastore.store]
[glance_store]
stores = rbd
default_store = rbd
rbd_store_pool = images
rbd_store_user = glance
rbd_store_ceph_conf = /etc/ceph/ceph.conf
rbd_store_chunk_size = 8
[image_format]
disk_formats = ami,ari,aki,vhd,vhdx,vmdk,raw,qcow2,vdi,iso,ploop.root-tar
[keystone_authtoken]
password = password 
username = glance
project_name = service
user_domain_name = Default
project_domain_name = Default
auth_type = password
memcached_servers = controller:11211
auth_url = http://controller:5000
www_authenticate_uri = http://controller:5000
[oslo_concurrency]
[oslo_messaging_amqp]
[oslo_messaging_kafka]
[oslo_messaging_notifications]
[oslo_messaging_rabbit]
[oslo_middleware]
[oslo_policy]
[paste_deploy]
flavor = keystone
[profiler]
[store_type_location_strategy]
[task]
[taskflow_executor]
```

Comment: After rmoving --protected switch, the error changed to *'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'*

Comment: I think this is merely a bug. Workaround is to leave out `--protected`, as you found out already, and to protect the image with `openstack image set ...`. However, I don't know either where the new error message comes from, and if it means any harm.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when I paste error here, It became human readable and I could read it. As you can see here:

> Provided object does not match schema 'image': 'True' is not of type 'boolean': Failed validating 'type' in schema['properties']**['*protected*']**

After I removed `--protected` switch from command, it throwed this exception:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

but it worked like a charm! I've no idea what happened!
Hope it helps :)